# what's the purpose of parameter ‘data’ in SDCacheQueryCompletedBlock

Tags: nsdata, sdwebimage

```
typedef void(^SDCacheQueryCompletedBlock)(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSData * _Nullable data, SDImageCacheType cacheType);
```

what's the purpose of the second parameter 'data' since I can not find anywhere using it?

Comment: Look at the changelog, and search for "For #1575 GIF support using FLAnimatedImage, several changes were needed:".

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ChangeLog](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

For #1575 GIF support using `FLAnimatedImage`, several changes were needed:
• replaced type `SDWebImageQueryCompletedBlock` with `SDCacheQueryCompletedBlock` and added an `NSData *` param
• because of the change above, the done param of `SDImageCache` `queryDiskCacheForKey:done:` is now a `SDCacheQueryCompletedBlock` and those blocks must now include an `NSData *` param
• replaced type `SDWebImageCompletionWithFinishedBlock` with `SDInternalCompletionBlock` and added an `NSData *` param
• because of the change above, the completed param of `SDWebImageManager` `loadImageWithURL:options:progress:completed:` is now `SDInternalCompletionBlock` and those blocks must now include an `NSData *` param 
• for consistency with the previous change, also renamed `SDWebImageCompletionBlock` to `SDExternalCompletionBlock` 
• `UIImage` will no longer respond to `sd_animatedGIFNamed:` or `sd_animatedImageByScalingAndCroppingToSize:`

***tl;dr:***
Change because of `FLAnimatedImage`.